# Computer says it's full, how do I move programs from C drive to other drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Our PC is always telling me the C drive is nearly full. I have diligently gone through everything and removed anything I don't absolutely need and no documents are on C. Still it says I have only 8% space, not even enough space to defrag anymore. How do I move programs from C drive to D drive without having to uninstall and reinstall them all? In the past I have found that when I moved things from C to D, then there is some kind of broken link and the files can't be opened at all. Please help, Thanx!

Comment: If you want to move applications you will have to reinstall them

Comment: Generally, you cannot move *installed programs* because the paths to said programs are saved in other places. There are ways around this, though. More importantly, how much actual space do you have, both total and free remaining? It may also be worthwhile to check what's actually using the most space with something like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/).

Comment: try to use http://windirstat.info/ to find where files are hiding.

Comment: See an alternate procedure to move data, not programs https://superuser.com/questions/1482103/how-to-move-locations-of-quick-access-items-to-another-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general solution and it's called a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

You can move any (program or video game installation) folder to another location and create a symbolic link at its old location referring to the new one. Example:

1. Move `C:\some\path\Amnesia A Machine For Pigs` to `D:\some\other\path\Amnesia A Machine For Pigs` with the file manager.
2. Run the following command (e. g. from a command line window a.k.a. `cmd.exe`):

   ```
   mklink /D "C:\some\path\Amnesia" "D:\some\other\path\Amnesia"
   ```